# How can i put the same code (header/footer) in multiple pages, knowing that I´m not using data or php, only HTML CSS JS

Tags: javascript, html

I got multiple error that would like to share with you:

First one: I´m using Document Fragment to put new divs/a/im and seems like i can only create 1 document fragment for 1 page, because in the second one doesn´t work.

```
const albumPoint = document.querySelector(".main-container-2");
let documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

let ListOfLinksPictures = ETc ETC ETC;

for (var i = 1; i <= 127; i++) {
  let plusDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
  plusDiv.classList.add("div-responsive-ag");

  let plusDiv2 = document.createElement("DIV");
  plusDiv2.classList.add("div-gallery");

  let plusA = document.createElement("A");

  let plusImg = document.createElement("IMG");

  plusA.setAttribute("href", ListOfLinksPictures[i]);
  plusA.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  plusImg.setAttribute("src",ListOfLinksPictures[i]);

  console.log("¡Este array, lista, contiene : " + 
    ListOfLinksPictures.length + "elementos!")

  plusDiv.appendChild(plusDiv2);
  plusDiv2.appendChild(plusA);
  plusA.appendChild(plusImg);
  documentFragment.appendChild(plusDiv);
}

albumPoint.appendChild(documentFragment);
```

Second I´m using this code in head document to repeat same header for multiple pages but it gives me bugs when im using multiple scripts option like ScrollReveal, the code is this one:

```
<script
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#header").load("header.html"); 
    $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
    });
</script> 
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: As far as I see, you haven't shared a single error message. Also, why is this tagged with CSS, but does not contain a single line of CSS?

Comment: @NicoHaase, You're right, im learning how to question here, I´m just editing it rn.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use JavaScript to load the header and footer into each page dynamically:
   In the head of each HTML page, include a script that uses `jQuery` or plain JavaScript to fetch the contents of the header and footer files and insert them into the respective containers on the page. This way, any updates to the header or footer will automatically be reflected on all pages that include them. Here's an example using jQuery:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Page</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(function() {
          $('#header').load('header.html');
          $('#footer').load('footer.html');
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="header"></div>
      <main>
        <!-- Main content goes here -->
      </main>
      <div id="footer"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2. Use server-side includes (SSI):
   If your server supports it, you can use server-side includes to include the header and footer in each page. This involves inserting a special SSI tag in each HTML file that includes the contents of the header and footer files at the specified location. Here's an example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <!--#include virtual="/path/to/header.html" -->
      <main>
        <!-- Main content goes here -->
      </main>
      <!--#include virtual="/path/to/footer.html" -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Note that this method requires server-side support for SSI and may not be available on all servers.

Regarding your first issue with `DocumentFragment`, it's hard to say what's causing the problem without seeing the rest of your code and error messages. However, keep in mind that a `DocumentFragment` is a temporary container that can hold multiple elements before they are added to the document, so you should be able to create multiple `DocumentFragment` objects and add them to different parts of the page.

As for the second issue with jQuery and multiple scripts, make sure that you're including jQuery before any other scripts that rely on it. Also, make sure that you're not including multiple copies of jQuery or other scripts, as this can cause conflicts and errors. You can use your browser's developer tools to check for errors in the console and debug any issues.